# Difficulty adjusting to body after I fixed anterior pelvic tilt

Tags: squats, deadlifts

I had the symptoms of anterior pelvic tilt, and measured it roughly by standing back and feet against a door and measuring the gap between my lower back and the door.  I did the corrective exercises (glute bridges, hip flexor stretches, etc.) and that gap narrowed significantly.

After I corrected this anterior pelvic tilt, I get lower back pain (a sudden pull during the lift and then 'strain' type pain that lasts for days) when I squat and deadlift.  I used to be able to squat and deadlift a good amount of weight.  Now even after lowering my weight significantly, I hurt myself.

How long will it take to get back up to normal?  I assume this is from my body having to use new (more appropriate) muscles in the lift.  Any more advice on getting back to normal?

Comment: How good was your squat and deadlift form prior to practicing the corrective exercise? I'm reminded of how when competitive bodybuilders start practicing functional exercises like tire flips, they tend to pull and tear their biceps because their muscles are so imbalanced.  It seems like you should try to "reset" your movement patterns -- forget about what your previous weight was for a couple of months and just practice quality reps with perfect form.  Your musculature will balance out and you'll be up above your previous maxes in no time (thanks to the new muscle recruitment).  Good luck!

Comment: @Doc: That _is_ good advice. You should put that as an answer (maybe fluff it up), so it's easier to find.

Comment: So...you read symptoms on the internet, self diagnosed, self corrected, and now you get pain when doing exercises that didn't used to give you pain. Can I ask why you thought you had/needed to correct for anterior tilt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be that you need additional mobilization... but after doing that I've lost a lot of power. All that what kept my junctions in place was removed, but muscles ware not familiar with my typical load.

Other case - you need to build both antagonist muscle groups. For instance strong chest, and weak trapezius moves your shoulders to the front, and can lead to pain in your back. That is why people use full training plans, works with personal trainers, or read a lot. Personally - I'm in the last group - I love to know how it works. No matter what it is.

BTW: Asking for medical advice is off-topic here.